# Does queries using `query()` method in php-activerecord is valid at migrating?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, activerecord

Lets say i am launching a query with MySQL syntax using PHPActiverecord's [Model::query()](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Model#methodquery) and in project deployment phase, target SQLServer will be Oracle.

I wonder to know does my query in `MySQL` still valid at deployment?

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder to know does my query in MySQL still valid at deployment?

It depends.

Mysql and Oracle has different SQL dialects.
If you are going to use two databases, then you should avoid raw queries, as most likely you will run into incompatible statement errors.

To offer compatibility is one of the AR purposes. That's why you should use only AR methods and avoid running raw queries.

Comment: `That's why you should use only AR methods and avoid running raw queries`: Yes, in my early implementation i was using AR's methods, but in one case(which i am trying to fix) average query time using AR is almost 3sec!! but with raw query its average time reduced down to 1sec!

Comment: So what? What's the use of a query that wouldn't work in production environment at all? where did you get that idea to develop using mysql while target DBMS is Oracle?

Comment: LOL, at first i said `**Lets say** i am launching...` means **assuming**; I just don't want to limit my application just to use `MySQL`, That is why i start using AR in the first place! :)

Comment: If you don't want to limit your application just to use MySQL, then you have to avoid raw SQL queries.